# App_Data Path from test unit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xunit.net

I am using XUnit for my test cases on a WebAPI2 web service.
I have a call to get the `App_Data` directory using

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("DataDirectory").ToString();
```

This returns the correct path when the application is published and run as normal but, when I am running my tests, It will not return the path to the `App_Data` directory.

I get this exception: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Any ideas how I can do this? I attempted to add an `App_Data` directory to my test project but it resulted in the same exception.

Essentially this is where I store an XML configuration file for an encryption utility that I need access to. Should I just move it to the root? If I do that, how would I access it from my test unit?

Comment: Sounds more like an integration test than a unit test... a unit test shouldn't really require anything in App_Data, should it?  With that said, I'm not sure how to get the test project to map that, but if I were doing integration testing, I would probably just provide the info in the config to the test app directly (e.g., hardcode/mock) instead of having it try to read the actual config.

Comment: @jdl134679, I went ahead and put it as a configuration setting in both my app.config and Web.config. post as an answer to get the points.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you copy the config to the test project (as an `app.config`) and then use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SettingName"]`, it'll pull from the app.config when running using the test project and the `web.config` when running using the MVC project.

Comment: this isn't the way to do it. unit tests should not have configuration files

Comment: @AndreiDragotoniu - I don't disagree (one of your upvotes is from me), and I mentioned as much in my originally comment to OP.  That said, just because he's using XUnit doesn't mean he's not writing integration tests instead of unit tests (integration test being what I'd classify anything that needs this configuration).

Comment: BTW, the test requires a template that is stored in the App_Data directory. That is acceptable use of that directory in a test unit.

Answer (score 3):

For this, I suggest you abstract away the configuration data retrieval.

Write an interface with one or more methods, if you need more, something like :

```
public interface IConfigurationData 
{
    string RetrieveConfigurationData()
}
```

the implementation of that would go to the App_Data folder on disk.
In your unit test you mock that interface and make it retrieve whatever configuration you need for your test.

A Unit test is not supposed to touch any external system, like a file or database or third party API. You abstract them away and mock them using something like RhinoMocks, or Moq, or NSubstitute, whatever you prefer.

The reason for this is that you want your unit tests to run as quickly as possible. The moment you introduce an actual system, like a file, they are not so quick anymore and as you add more unit tests, the execution time keeps going up. Ideally you want your unit tests to run in seconds, so you can run them as many times as you want, without delaying the development process.

Comment: +1, but I'd say a more important reason than the speed issue you've noted is that unit tests should target very small pieces of logic, which is more subtle but also makes them more resilient and ultimately of more use in the longrun (e.g., they should have little to zero external dependencies, be it from disk or elsewhere).

Comment: BTW, the test requires a template that is stored in the App_Data directory. That is acceptable use of that directory in a test unit.